# Sections in UITabelView with API data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working in swift 2.x and xcode 7.x and i am stuck with tabelviews and api data. Everywere i look i need to have 2 array's one with my object and one for the section. my current code is:

```
 //MARK: Setting up the tableview
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return eventsCollection.count
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let eventDate = self.eventsCollection[section].startDate
        let month = Utility.sharedInstance.convertToDateStringMonth(eventDate)
        return month
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.eventsCollection.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 70;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    return
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: EventCellView!
    cell = self.calenderTabelView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCellView") as! EventCellView
    cell.dayNameLabel.text = Utility.sharedInstance.getDayOfWeek(self.eventsCollection[indexPath.row].startDate)
    cell.dayNumberLabel.text = Utility.sharedInstance.convertToDataDay(self.eventsCollection[indexPath.row].startDate)
    cell.NewLabel.text = self.eventsCollection[indexPath.row].Name
    return cell
}
```

When i get the data i unwrap it and set it in the eventcollection. an exaple from an event is:

NOTE: this is the API response.

```
AllDay = 1;

Attendees =     (
); <as array>
Description = "Test Evenment"; <as string>
EndDate = "2017-02-03T23:59:59+00:00"; <as string>
ID = 173; <as int or string>
Name = "Test evenement"; <string>
StartDate = "2016-11-01T00:00:00+00:00"; <string>
VenueName = "Appbakkers HQ";} <string>
```

when i run the code it devides the tabelview in sections with the name of the month as title header. But i need to sort the event into the right month. for example the one in june only needs to appear once in june and when i add an otherwone in june it needs to go there.

so tableview look like this:

june

cell for january

cell for june

january

cell for january

cell for june

what i want is

june:

cell for june

january

cell for january

```
the function getDayOfWeek -> monday thueseday ,etc as a string
the function convertToDataDay -> 1 - 31 as a string
the function convertToDateStringMonth -> june, juli, etc. as string
```

any input would help me along! Thanks for any replies.

ADDITIONAL:

```
class Event: NSObject {
    //the event class
    var id:Int = 0
    var Description: String = ""
    var endDate: String = ""
    var Name: String = ""
    var startDate: String = ""
    var venueName: String = ""
//    var Attendees: NSDictionary = [:] havent figuerd this part out also
}

    func mapComment(responseObject: AnyObject) -> Event{

        let EventObject = Event()

//        let andenteesObject = responseObject["Attendees"]

        if let ID = responseObject["id"] as? Int {
            EventObject.id = ID
        } else if let ID = responseObject["id"] as? String {
            EventObject.id = Int(ID)!
        }

        if let despription = responseObject["Description"] as? String{
            EventObject.Description = despription
        }
        if let startDate = responseObject["StartDate"] as? String{
            EventObject.startDate = startDate
        }
        if let endDate = responseObject["EndDate"] as? String{
            EventObject.endDate = endDate
        }
        if let name = responseObject["Name"] as? String{
            EventObject.Name = name
        }
//        if let attendees = andenteesObject as? NSDictionary{
//            EventObject.Attendees = attendees
//        }
        return EventObject
    }
}
```

so i have 2 questions actually:

1. How to i sort my data in and month array
2. How do i get my data from that array in the tableview?

Comment: Can you show the json response that you are getting, That will be more helpful.

Comment: i did its the parts from an example even. added a note to make it more clear

Comment: Not like that put at least one response that you want to show with section and its cell

Comment: i want to sort each event into the month it takes place in. so all events in june in the section june

Comment: i want to show the weekday its taking place in. the day of the month and the title of the event. in each cell. in sections of months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good, little modification is needed. Basically you need to maintain an attendees by month and separate dates array, here is how it can be done,

```
var eventsByMonth : [String : [Event]] = [:]

// store as date, its easy to sort (but anyway you like) 
var months = [NSDate]()

// iterate over response and store according to month,
for event in events {

  //convert the string to date (you can find it easily)
  let startDate = convertStringtoDate(event.startDate)

  months.append(startDate)

  // now split events by months 
  let month = Utility.sharedInstance.convertToDateStringMonth(event.StartDate)

  var temp = eventsByMonth[month] ?? []
  temp.append(event)

  eventsByMonth[month] = temp
}

months = sortDate(months) // sort anyway you like
```

so now you can use the months array to get the counts to the tableView like below,

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return months.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let month =  months[section]

    guard let monthEvents = eventsByMonth[month] else {
        return 0
    }

    return monthEvents.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let month =  months[section]
    let monthEvents = events[month]!

    let event = monthEvents[indexPath.row]

    // configure your cell
}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: atendee is an array in the event the structure is like this event[atendees[] other values;] so im not sure how the code above workes

Comment: by atendee,  i means single entity in that array, so any names works

Comment: i just tried to explain the logic, look for that, so in your point, you can iterate over the array and store the indivual object accordingly to its startDate and store the startDate in seperate array to sort easily

Comment: so in 1 "atemdee" is my hole event object?

Comment: can you represent you response structure more clear, i can update answer if required, i understood as , attendees is array, so attendee is single object inside it, did i understood right ?

Comment: single or more you got it right. so its an object inside the event object with member in it that want to attend. its dynamicly. i want the event object wich takes place in a month to be on that months section. if i make any sence

Comment: oh i misunderstood i thought attendees is the one you wanted to show, an json sample structure would help me to update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118637/discussion-between-ramesh-and-cees).

Comment: sorry for the mistake the question editor was beeing wierd thanks!

Comment: lets continue chat in discussion, so that i can update the answer